# How to get the exact same output from mysqldump as mysqladmin/backup

Tags: mysql, mysqladministrator

On a very important Windows server we use a scheduled task set up by the mysqladmin utility to back up our critical data.

I'd like to use the simpler mysqldump command, but I want to ensure that the output is the same. Presumably mysqladmin and mysqldump both share a common core dumping component, so for any given setting in mysqladmin I ought to be able to find a configuration for mysqldump which produce the **exact same output**.

But how?

At the moment I am resorting to trial & error - but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Administrator does not actually use the same core dumping ability as mysqldump.  For some reason, it was reimplemented (and generally worse off than mysqldump uses).

So I would recommend you pick the options you most desire and use those in mysqldump.

Answer (score 2):

I would first dump some short tables with mysqladmin and the same tables with mysqldump. Then  I would check the differences and find the appropriate options to use using the [mysqldump manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing.... the trial & error approach. Can anybody suggest something better?